# Children to call parent function before Parent's `componentWillMount`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way in React for a child to sort of register itself by calling a function on parent to pass some of its props before the Parent's `componentWillMount` lifecycle method is called?

here is an example usecase

```
<Chart width={...} height={...} data={...} xAccessor={...}>
    <LineSeries yAccessor={...} />
    <AreaSeries yAccessor={...} />
    <SomeOtherSeries yAccessor={...} />
    <ThisIsNotASeriesComponent ... />
</Chart>
```

each of the `XXXSeries` has a `yAccessor` which it plots on the chart, but the `Chart` above has to create the scales for `y` and to do that it needs the domain, and to get the `domain`(a terminology from d3.js scales) it needs the `yAccessor` from its child.

The way I am doing this now is in the `componentWillMount` method of `Chart` I am iterating through all the children and reading their props, However I don't have to props of `ThisIsNotASeriesComponent` and there is no way for me to find out if a child is a Series or not.

This whole thing becomes more complicated if I have a set up like

```
<Chart width={...} height={...} data={...} xAccessor={...}>
    <Wrapper><AnotherWrapper>
        <LineSeries yAccessor={...} />
        <AreaSeries yAccessor={...} />
        <SomeOtherSeries yAccessor={...} />
        <ThisIsNotASeriesComponent ... />
    </AnotherWrapper></Wrapper>
</Chart>
```

I am the author of [react-stockcharts](https://github.com/rrag/react-stockcharts) and the examples are becoming bigger and complicated I would like to explore if there are alternative ways of reading child props from parent

Comment: Props are supposed to be immutable and are passed by the parent so must be known by the parent. Am I missing something here.

Comment: @JanakaStevens No, you're correct. If `<Chart/>` requires things from its children, then I think `<Chart/>` should be the child itself. @rrag Have you tried [react-d3](https://github.com/esbullington/react-d3)?

Comment: Just a start, look at https://github.com/calitek/ReactPatterns React.14/D3.

Comment: @JanakaStevens parent does not pass the props to the child, owner does. in my example `Chart` is parent of `LineSeries` and let us say this whole code was in the `render` method of a component called `MyChart` then `MyChart` is the owner.

Comment: @Mike I have used react-d3, I used to be one of the contributors too. It does not let you create compos-able charts, rather provides one single component - acceptable for simple charts, when you need deep customization you end up passing so many props to the `<XXXChart {...} />` and it is not possible for the users to create custom components and use them.

Comment: How does yAccessor change? If it is just a prop set manually then I would set them all on `<Chart lineAccessor={...} areaAccessor={...}/>` and pass them down. Then you have them set in `<Chart/>` when the component loads.

Comment: the `yAccessor` does not change, I cannot use `lineAccessor` at the `Chart` because I want to (and I do) support multiple `LineSeries`, but most importantly, I want the ability to add custom `XXXSeries` and doing that should not change the code of `Chart`